# Netbeans GUI editor doesn't support ASCII - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, ascii

So I'm making a basic GUI with the NetBeans IDE (in Java), and I want to make a button with a √ sign in it. It didn't let me copypaste it in, so I tried using its ASCII code - `char sqrt = (char) 251`. Instead of the square root sign, however, it gave me "û", and I have no idea why. Can someone please explain why this is happening, as well as offer an idea as to how I should go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java characters are Unicode, not ASCII.  Unicode codepoint 251 ([U+00FB](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fb/index.htm)) is "Latin Small Letter U with Circumflex".  To make input of various Unicode characters using a character set with only the basic ASCII symbols, Java provides a way to input Unicode characters using a literal format.  So, you can do this:

```
char sqrt = '\u221a';
```

since [U+221A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm) is the Unicode codepoint for the square root symbol.

This \uXXXX format can also be used in String literals:

```
String s = "The square root of 2 (\u221a2) is approximately 1.4142";
```

If you print that String, you will see

```
The square root of 2 (√2) is 1.4142
```

Comment: But how come this works (when I have it just by itself): `char sqrt = (char) 251; System.out.println(sqrt);`? At least it works when I compile it from the command line :o

Comment: My guess is that you're using Windows using a default file encoding of CP437, which maps the square root glyph to 0xFB (251), and so when the int with value 251 is being cast to a char, it sees that the character with codepoint 0xFB in the CP437 code page is the square root symbol, and uses that.

Answer (score 3):

Java uses Unicode, and the Unicode value for '√' is 8730. So, this should do it:

```
char sqrt = 8730;
```